# How to ckeck and display an image if there is one

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask for some help because I am stuck at that problem. I have a MySQL DB and I am trying to create some kind of a blog system. The problem which occure to me is this:
I would like to check is there is an image tag if not not to display it. The system works perfect without images but it would be nice if I new where I messed it up. Here is my code up to now:

```
function outputStory($article, $only_snippet = FALSE){
global $conn;


if($article){
    $sql = "SELECT ar.*, usr.name FROM cms_articles ar LEFT OUTER JOIN cms_users usr ON ar.author_id = usr.user_id WHERE ar.article_id = " . $article;
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<h2>" . htmlspecialchars($row['title']) . "</h2>\n";
    echo"<h5><div class='byLine'>От:" . htmlspecialchars($row['name']) . "</div>";
    echo "<div class='pubdate'>";
    if($row['is_published'] == 1){
        echo date("F j, Y",strtotime($row['date_published']));  
    } else {
        echo "No articles are published yet!";
    }
    echo "</div></h5>\n";
    if ($only_snippet){
        echo "<p>\n";
        echo nl2br(trimBody($row['body']));

       // I think I messed this statement alot but don't know how to make it work properly :S

        if(hasPostImage() == true){
            $getPostImage = "SELECT * FROM cms_images";
            $getImgResult = mysql_query($getPostImage,$conn);
            $rowImg = mysql_fetch_array($getImgResult);
            echo"<img src='".$rowImg['img_src']."' alt='".$rowImg['img_desc']."'>";

        } else {
            echo '<img style="display:none">';  
        }
        echo "</p>\n";
        echo "<h4><a href=\"viewarticle.php?article=" . $row['article_id'] . "\">More...</a></h4><br>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<p>\n";
        echo nl2br($row['body']);
        echo "</p>\n";  
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I hope the question is not silly or something else and thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Am I missing something, but shouldn't you show the code for the hasPostImage() function?

Comment: I didn't writen anything there because i don't know how to make the correct statement. Should I use that function or it is useless ?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, your question is lacking detail. What is hasPostImage() supposed to check? Your are selecting all from cms_images which also does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for doing this, my first approach is to first check you are getting file in `$_FILES` is its okay then there is functions available in PHP to check file size means this will give you files size in bytes and height and width as well. [File Size()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)

also [getimagesize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) if this criteria matches your criteria then proceed further

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what to do but am I on the right way with this statement ?
`if(isset($images)){
$sql = "SELECT im.*, ar.article_id FROM cms_images im LEFT OUTER JOIN cms_articles ar ON ar.image_id = img.image_id WHERE ar.article_id = " . $article;

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $_FILES[$row['img_name']];
$size = getimagesize($row);
}`